# In fallout the role-playing game, can supermutants make their own non-raider armor

Tags: equipment, armor, modiphius-2d20, fallout-the-role-playing-game

In fallout the role-playing game by Modiphus, on page 53 under super mutant, it says "you can only wear armor which has been made to fit a super mutant". In the same book, under raider armor on page 133, it says "Super mutant characters may only wear raider armor"

**So which is correct? Can super mutant characters only wear raider armor, only wear armor specifically made for super mutants, or only wear raider armor specifically made for super mutants and no other armor types?**

Would they, for example, be able to make their own armor at an armor station or have someone else in the party do so to specifically fit them, even if its not raider armor?

Comment: In context, is it possible that the game's just unclearly distinguishing between literally and proficiently? That is, could the first case mean *you can only wear armor* that fits, and the second case mean you *may only wear raider armor* competently? (Please excuse me if, in fact, the game makes this distinction totally clear. I know nothing about this game, but my experience with RPGs means I've seen games be unclear on this point before—Palladium, if memory serves, has an especially rough patch around its armor rules, for instance.)

Comment: As far as I can tell, proficiency is not a thing. Any PC can wear any armor they have the carrying capacity for, with the exception of robots that can only use robot plating and super mutants, which have these two seemingly contradictory entries.

Comment: read through the rules, there is no armor proficiency. There is no such thing as using armor but not competently or anything like that

Comment: That's cool. Unless you think it's distracting, I'll let my comment stand in case other readers assume similar.

Comment: so reading through the item creation rules, there are rules for modifying armor but none for making it from scratch. I am wondering if they can only use raider armor because raider armor is just metal plates and leather stripes tied together with straps, so if the straps are long enough it can fit a super mutant. Maybe the line about can only use armor made for them is in there in case a future expansion adds rules fro creating armor and weapons from scratch?

Comment: @Andrew tour guess looks reasonable, but we declared speculation about designer intent off topic on this site, because it hardly can be anything more than a speculation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have received the following e-mail info from Modiphius:

> Good afternoon,
>
> One of our writers has responded regarding your Super Mutant query:
> "Super-mutants can only wear Raider armour, which represents the
> improvised armour that super mutants typically wear"
>
> Kind regards and happy new year,  Chris Dann Customer Service
> Representative Modiphius Entertainment Ltd

This has been further cleared up to me by a Modiphius moderator on the errata thread:

> Modiphius-Nathan Modiphius Staff 13h You’re overcomplicating things
> here by assuming that it should be specifically modded or crafted.
> Look at the armour super-mutants actually wear in the games: it’s
> rags, lengths of chain, sheet metal bent roughly into shape, and so
> forth. There’s not much “modding” or “crafting” involved.
>
> Similarly, raider armour in the games is essentially junk roughly
> assembled into a suit of armour.
>
> Any item of raider armour can be worn by a super-mutant. It doesn’t
> require special crafting or modding: a super mutant character will
> find some way to make it fit, by brute force if need be.
>
> The intial plan was for a dedicated set of super-mutant armour… but it
> was a waste of page space to include, as it provided basically the
> same protection as raider armour and differed only in terms of size.

I am glad to finally have a satisfactory answer. They can only use raider armor, which they can easily adjust to fit them if they loot it.

Comment: (I think it's a bit unfair to say you were overcomplicating things. The game says that "you can only wear armor which has been made to fit a super mutant," so one assumes *made* here means *crafted* not *improvised*. I mean, if you were told that you could only wear shoes that have been made to fit, I don't think you (or anyone) would immediately think of ***making** the shoes fit* by cutting them in half and duct taping them around your feet!)